# Android Effective way to Search Apk File

Tags: android, file, apk, share

Warm Greetings to All,

I am developing free APK Share application which search for all the apk files(INCLUDING THOSE NOT INSTALLED ON DEVICE) stored in My Android Device.i have almost completed the application But I would like to make this application some more effective.

As of now whenever the application Opens up i am scanning the device for all apk files in it.But i need the scan to be done if and only if some new apk files been added or the existing one is modified.I would be glad to get some idea to do this.Please give me some suggestions about it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can listen to broadcasts and then update your model:

```
    <receiver android:name=".AppInstallOrRemoveReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..will this works only for installed apk's or also for the apk files which is not installed in device?

Comment: This will only work for installed apk files. I think you cannot create a broadcastreceiver (perhaps a background service, which I would not recommend) for specific files.

Comment: PACKAGE_ADDED: Broadcast Action: A new application package has been installed on the device

Comment: @Mdlc: can you please tell me shall i use FileObserver to do it?

Comment: I would rather suggest keeping a list of apk files from the previous session and load that when your app opens. On the background you can search for new apk's and add them to the list.

Comment: @Mdlc:Thanks a lot for your sugeestion :)